# Functional Javascript: Having trouble iterating through an object that has nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I'm having difficulty trying to access my data in a table structured as below. I want a clean and efficient way of accessing my nested data through a functional Javascript approach. If anyone can show how this can be done functionally using Ramda or plain ES6 it'd be much appreciated! Please see the example table structure below.

---

```
let tables = {
  table1: {
    headings: [ 'hey', 'there' ],
    rows: [ 'row 1 here', 'row 2 here' ],
  },
  table2: {
    headings: [ 'sup', 'yall' ],
    rows: [ 'row1 3 here', 'row 4 here' ],
  },
  table3: {
    headings: [ 'what', 'up' ],
    rows: [ 'row 5 here', 'row 6 here' ],
  },
}
```

### Edit

I am using React and my end goal is for me to construct each table within a Table Component, so I am hoping to be able to something like below within the component 

`const headings = [ 'hey', 'there' ]
const rows = [ 'row 1 here', 'row 2 here' ]`

Comment: This is confusing, generally you'd do `tables.table2.headings[0]`, how would you do that with functional programming or Ramda ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Could you please update the question with a definition of what you mean by _access my data_?

Comment: Yeah so confusing..i'm working on someone else's project and have requested to do it in this way. I've been playing with Ramda the past day but have struggled to get what i need.

Comment: What do you need to do?? Seems odd someone asked you "Please access this data with Ramda", there must be a little more specificity to the task.

Comment: Even your edit is confusing.  It's not clear what you mean (and I don't think the missing verb is the main issue.)  With that data structure as an input, what sorts of functions do you want?  What additional parameters would they include?  For instance, would you want something as simple as `headings('table2', tables); //=> ['sup', 'yall']`?  That would be easy to write, with or without Ramda.  Or do you need something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to enumerate the data structure, something like this would work:

```js
let tables = {
  table1: {
    headings: ['hey', 'there'],
    rows: ['row 1 here', 'row 2 here'],
  },
  table2: {
    headings: ['sup', 'yall'],
    rows: ['row1 3 here', 'row 4 here'],
  },
  table3: {
    headings: ['what', 'up'],
    rows: ['row 5 here', 'row 6 here'],
  },
};


Object.keys(tables).forEach((tableId) => {

  tables[tableId].headings.forEach((heading) => {
    // do something with heading
  });

  tables[tableId].rows.forEach((row) => {
    // do something with the row
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @skav! Exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is to transform the data (as opposed to process some side-effects on it), then Ramda does have some tools to make it easier, especially [`evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve).

If you had a function that you wanted to used for the body elements such as this:

```
const surround = (tag) => (content) => `<${tag}>${content}</${tag}>`;
```

and you wanted to upper-case the headers, you could use something like this

```
R.map(R.evolve({
  headings: R.map(R.toUpper),
  rows: R.map(surround('td'))
}))(tables);
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?let%20tables%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20table1%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20headings%3A%20%5B%27hey%27%2C%20%27there%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rows%3A%20%5B%27row%201%20here%27%2C%20%27row%202%20here%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20table2%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20headings%3A%20%5B%27sup%27%2C%20%27yall%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rows%3A%20%5B%27row1%203%20here%27%2C%20%27row%204%20here%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20table3%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20headings%3A%20%5B%27what%27%2C%20%27up%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rows%3A%20%5B%27row%205%20here%27%2C%20%27row%206%20here%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20surround%20%3D%20curry%28%28tag%2C%20content%29%20%3D%3E%20%60%3C%24%7Btag%7D%3E%24%7Bcontent%7D%3C%2F%24%7Btag%7D%3E%60%29%3B%0A%0Amap%28evolve%28%7B%0A%20%20headings%3A%20map%28toUpper%29%2C%0A%20%20rows%3A%20map%28surround%28%27td%27%29%29%0A%7D%29%2C%20tables%29%3B)**.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var key in tables ) {
    for (var innerKey tables[key] ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tables[key][innerKey].length; i++) {
            console.log(tables[key][innerKey][i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Plenty of examples on looping over objects and arrays out there